# Origin of "minibeasts"?

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the term *minibeasts*?

Growing up in the UK I never heard the term, but recently I have heard it prolifically used in preschool education and children's television programmes.

Comment: A cursory check on Google suggests the usage was popularised (though probably not *coined*) in the early 70s, as part of the UK's [Science 5/13 initiative](http://www.nationalstemcentre.org.uk/elibrary/collection/594/science-5-13). One of the textbooks was [**Minibeasts** Stages 1 and 2:  A unit for teachers](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/Minibeasts-Stages-Science-513-unit-teachers/11486268900/bd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minibeast** or "Minibeasts" is a term for a variety of arthropods and other invertebrates, including spiders, ants, butterflies, bees, wasps, flies, woodlice [1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minibeast%2Cminibeasts&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminibeast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminibeasts%3B%2Cc0), and many others. The United Kingdom-based Young People's Charitable Trust defines them as "small animals" in a factsheet written for young readers [2]. There is a "Minibeast Zooseum" in Michigan dedicated to invertebrates[3].**Minibeasts, as indicated by their name, are generally 'mini' or small.**

**The study of minibeasts is common as part of the primary school curriculum.** **Studying minibeasts is a very effective way to observe many biological concepts first hand, which is not possible with many larger animals.** Life cycles, food chains, and bodily structure and function are just some of the basic elements of biological science which can be easily explained using minibeasts. "Bugs Alive!" at Melbourne Museum features a huge number of live minibeasts with detailed information about them, while services such as "Minibeast Wildlife" [4] and "Travelbugs" [5] take live minibeast to schools and provide educational resources.

Source: Wiki

The term has become very popular since  1980 as shown on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=minibeast%2Cminibeasts&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cminibeast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminibeasts%3B%2Cc0), apparently with the educational trend developed in those years.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's all *that* popular - if I [add "**arthropod**" to your NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Minibeast%2Carthropod&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMinibeast%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Carthropod%3B%2Cc0), it totally flatlines. And to be honest I'd hardly have said even **arthropod** was a particularly popular word. But it's worth noting that of the four capitalisation/pluralisation permutations, you chose to graph the least common (the most common is *plural, no capitalisation*).

Comment: As OP noticed,the term  it is widely  used in preschool education and children's TV programmes, but, I guess, totally unknown to those not involved in those specific contexts. As for NGram; what is interesting is that it shows that the term has become popular since the 80's with the introduction of the subject in primary schools. I am not sure that a comparison with arthropod is really meaningful, a term which is much older and used in different contexts with respect to minibeast.

Comment: I only chose *arthropod* because it was the first word I saw when casting about looking for a term that most children probably wouldn't know. I'd never noticed the term until now - but even without context it's pretty obvious what it's likely to "mean". What I don't understand is why OP has accepted this answer - firstly, it's almost entirely [a cut&pasted Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibeast), and secondly, it doesn't actually address the question *"What is the origin?"*. But I guess if OP is happy, why should I complain?

Comment: I accepted it because I am quite new to the English site and found the NGram thing very interesting.  I once asked another question on here which had links to other interesting online etymology tools but it was closed (so the tool links are gone). :(

Comment: I guess you are referring to the link: http://www.etymonline.com/

Comment: In my day we called them "creepy crawlies".

Comment: A note explaining that the Ngram has been updated, otherwise visitors will read FF comments and think nothing is changed.