# A hypernym for 'insects', 'worms' and the like

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, nuance

From Oxford:

**[insect](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/insect)**:

> any small creature with six legs and a body divided into three parts. Insects usually also have wings. Ants, bees and flies are all insects
>
> Insect is often used to refer to other small creatures, for example spiders, although this is not correct scientific language.

**[worm](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/worm)**:

> 1. a long thin creature with no bones or legs, that lives in soil
> 2. long thin creatures that live inside the bodies of humans or animals and can cause illness
> 3. the young form of an insect when it looks like a short worm

I find both these definitions oddly restrictive. Insects have 6 legs and worms (in the primary sense) have none. The other senses of worm are also specific. There are many small creatures who do not fall into these categories. Centipedes definity have legs, and a lot more than six. Is there a common (not too scientific) word to refer to all small creatures?

---

A **[bug](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bug)** doesn't work, as is defined as

> *chiefly North American* A small **insect**:
>
> *a thick green scum which crawls with bugs, centipedes, and worse*

Insect, not creature, not worm. Also note the exclusion of centipedes from the umbrella of bugs. In fact, Oxford defines [centipedes](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/centipede) exclusively in scientific terms.

> A **predatory myriapod invertebrate** with a flattened elongated body composed of many segments. Most segments bear a single pair of legs, the front pair being modified as poison fangs.

Although Oxford [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/insect) lists an informal sense of insect:

> *informal* Any small invertebrate animal such as a spider or tick.

It curiously drops this definition in the advanced learners' version. Moreover, it's reluctant to use the term in its own definition of [spider](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spider):

> An eight-legged **predatory arachnid** with an unsegmented body consisting of a fused head and thorax and a rounded abdomen. Spiders have fangs which inject poison into their prey, and most kinds spin webs in which to capture insects.

---

**Questions:**

- Is there any word, preferably not too informal, which would include all small creatures like insects, worms, spiders and centipedes; without having to resort to biological jargon?
- Also, how right/wrong is it to use `insect` or `bug` for this purpose?

Comment: For all those critters _except worms_, the word is arthropods. Worms, however are not arthropods. You can choose to ignore biology, but worms are simply very, very different. You could go for _critters_, which would prolly include all you mentioned. Insect is plain wrong, spiders and worms are not insects. As for _bug_, it excludes worms as well according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bug).

Comment: I don't know if you'd consider ***invertebrates*** to be "biological jargon", but it would work for me - either ignore bigger ones like octopuses and giant squid, or go for ***small** invertebrates*.

Comment: @oerkelens: Thanks for agreeing. And for the suggestion.

Comment: In addition to using FumbleFingers's scientifically accurate (and widely understood) suggestion _invertebrates_, you might use the phrase "animals without backbones."

Comment: I find ODO's restriction of *bug* to insects to be overly restrictive. My understanding of it is closer to AHD: *[b. An insect of any kind, such as a cockroach or a ladybug. c. A small invertebrate with many legs, such as a spider or a centipede.](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bug)*. I don't consider worms to be *bugs*, but perhaps they fall under MW's definition: *[an insect or other creeping or crawling invertebrate (as a spider or centipede)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bug)*

Comment: @choster: Thanks for the AHD link. That's the best and most comprehensive entry, I think.

Comment: @oerkelens: My bad.

Comment: I would consider "bug", informally, to include insects, as well as both centipedes and arachnids. I can't think of any term that would include both insects and worms, however, without also including other vermin such as snakes.

Comment: @oerkelens: "Worms" are not a taxonomic group. Among living things that are called worms, some are not arthropods but others are -- such as many insect larvae.

Comment: There is also **critters** itself.

Comment: I expect questions on etymology on this site; I'm amused by the question on entomology!

Comment: *Invertebrates* probably wouldn't work, because it would also include things like crabs and jellyfish.

Comment: It would be great if you provided details on **the context** of usage. Without it it's hard to say whether each of the answers is acceptable or not.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: It's what I said: Not informal, not scientific, not downright incorrect by being restrictive. Anyway, I accepted 'minibeasts'

Comment: It used to irk me that worms, snails and slugs were considered bugs, but I have now embraced the colloquial meaning of the term. "Bug" is not a scientific term, and neither is it a synonym for insect or arthropod. You could say that (wait for it) it doesn't bug me anymore.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Small children are easily interested in small creatures and, unsurprisingly, primary schools in Britain find the study of such animals a good starting point for much of the curriculum. However, it is was thought that calling them "creepy-crawlies" would risk alienating pupils and trigger the fear and distaste which was common in their grandparents' day.

So the term for these small creatures most often used in British Primary Education is **[minibeasts](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minibeast#English)** For a general view of UK minibeast history [see this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibeast).

> "Minibeast" or "Minibeasts" is a term for **a variety of arthropods and other invertebrates**, including spiders, ants, butterflies, bees, wasps, flies, woodlice [1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minibeast#English), and many others.

Comment: Related link: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166006/origin-of-minibeasts

Comment: @TusharRaj I added a link to your wiktionary page, but, re-reading it find the definition to be essentially limited to "insects and bugs", with "etc" leaving the rest to the imagination.

Comment: @MARGANA: Gotta love the `etc`! Anyway, here's the [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibeast)

Comment: Being from the U.S. I haven't heard this, but I do like it. Unfortunately, without having the actual definition there I might think small animals were included as well depending on the context it was used in. (like mice, squirrels, etc)

Comment: @DoubleDouble: No, wikipedia specifically limits the scope to invertebrates.

Comment: I wonder if that word was inspired by (diminutive-crazed) Dutch, which has "beestje" -- "beastlet".

Comment: @TusharRaj I'm aware of that, since the definition is right there. I was saying as somebody who hasn't heard the term before, The term is clear enough that I have an idea of what it is, but I wouldn't go to Wikipedia to see the exact definition if I came across it in text, so the wrong meaning may get across to me if its really so important for the OP to distinguish between these. Since it says its mostly a British term, that might be more or less of a risk depending on the audience.

Comment: Does  "minibeast" also include crabs and other crustaceans, which are also arthropods? Some crabs can grow much larger than some vertebrate critters such as mice or squirrels!  It seems "minibeast" must have some kind of size limit, or it becomes quite vague indeed.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock "Is there a common (not too scientific) word to refer to all _small creatures_?" [my italics] is what the question asks, so we might assume that minibeasts are "small creatures". Of course, it does depend on what you mean by "small", but we kind of know, don't we? The word should be "not too scientific", so not too tightly defined?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Some crabs can indeed be larger than some vertebrates, but so can some insects (eg Goliath beetle at 11.5 cm) or worms (the bootlace worm can reach 50m in length). Some mammals (eg shrews) can be smaller in length than many caterpillars.

Comment: I disagree with the promulgation of this term. Not only does the term suggest a superset of "creepy-crawlies," but I think it teaches the wrong lesson. The fact is that our revulsion toward these creatures is adaptive, not arbitrary -- many carry disease; they count many parasites among their numbers; they generally indicate decay. The point should be that we need to cultivate curiosity in *spite* of revulsion. The dissection of cadavers is a good example. The cadaver taboo held back our understanding of anatomy for centuries.

Comment: Re size: At least one definition of minibeast is *any invertebrate that fits in the palm of a hand*. So that rules out mice and large crabs.

Comment: Oh, good. I wasn't really sure if it applies to sea creatures.  So it would include "small" species of crab (and maybe young crab of larger species?) as well as shrimp, barnacles, clams etc.  many of these are far from creepy, and some clearly do not crawl.

Answer (score 80):

[*Creepy-crawlies*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/creepy-crawly).

> informal
>   A spider, worm, or other small flightless creature, especially when considered unpleasant or frightening:

^ Covers all three cases.

---

Also, despite your dictionary defining "bug" as an insect specifically, i wouldn't balk at using it to describe worms or spiders as well.

Comment: +1 for your footnote especially. Also *critter* (especially in the Southern U.S.).

Comment: @DanBron: Oxford isn't really in touch with AmE, I'm beginning to think. It defines [critter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/critter) as any animal, and says the word is a variant of creature.

Comment: @TusharRaj I'm not surprised.

Comment: @Scimonster: [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critter) says the same thing.

Comment: I happen to agree with that definition of "critter". There's a reason i didn't include it in my answer.  @TusharRaj

Comment: Entomology be damned, I can't see how one can conceive of the demotic use of "bug" as _excluding_ spiders and centipedes. Worms, no.

Comment: "From ghouls and ghosties and long-leggedy beasties, and things that go bump in the night, Good Lord deliver us."

Comment: @TusharRaj No, that's 100% right too. But entomologists in the Southern U.S. will happily tell you they study *critters*, because that covers insects, arthropods, arachnids, annelids, isopods, etc, and communicate their field clearly while still avoiding the charge of pedantry. The same region also applies *critter* to microscopic organisms as well as animalia more broadly, so context is required to disambiguate. See, as an arbitrary example, the [*Kentucky **Critter** Files*](http://www.uky.edu/Ag/CritterFiles/casefile/casefile.htm) at the entomology dept of the U of Kentucky.

Comment: @DanBron: Nice link. It's less foggy now.

Comment: I agree with @David, "bug" covers insects, spiders and centipedes, but *not* worms (unless the "worm" is really an insect, for instance an inchworm).  I've only ever heard *critter* as a synonym for "creature" and generally meaning a small to mid-sized animal (mammal, reptile or amphibian).

Comment: I think of "critter" as any smallish animal - rats, yes, rabbits, yes, lizards, yes, dogs and cats, no. Also, large lizards like say komodo dragons, also no.

Comment: My relatives in the northern US use "bug" to describe any invertebrate that is small and "gross". Insects, snails, slugs, worms, etc. My family from the south uses critter occasionally, but that is usually for some variety of pest insect (like a flea) and it also extends to squirrels and such.

Comment: The intersection of the terms "worm" and "bug" is very small: it applies informally to inch-worms and potentially other caterpillars, maybe centipedes or millipedes (which are much more "bug" than "worm"), but there's no world in which a nightcrawler or garden worm is a "bug".

Answer (score 32):

**Bug** is certainly what I would use, and what I would expect those around me to use. And I am American, so I think Oxford is simply wrong about how we use the word. Merriam-Webster, for instance, gives [the principal definition of bug](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bug) as

> 1
>   a :  an insect or other creeping or crawling invertebrate (as a spider or centipede)

This matches your desired usage perfectly. Note the near-reference to Scimonster’s suggestion of *creepy-crawlies* – Merriam-Webster here makes it pretty clear that *bug* is used as a more-formal *creepy-crawly*.

That said, if we are being truly formal (read: technical), the third definition is the “formal” one:

> 1
>   c :  any of an order (*Hemiptera* and especially its suborder *Heteroptera*) of insects that have sucking mouthparts, forewings thickened at the base, and incomplete metamorphosis and are often economic pests —called also *true bug*

This fact is, however, outside entomology, not widely known, and would be regarded by most as trivia. By comparison, the specifics of *insect* are much more widely known, though I’d guess the majority of speakers are unlikely to care very much in practice – just because someone knows, or at least at one point learned, that insects have three body parts, six legs, etc., doesn’t mean they care to use the word so exactly. But many more know/care about *insect*’s specific definition than do about *bug*, as indicated by the fact that some entomologists have resorted to the phrase *true bug* for *Heteroptera*. Thus bug is very much my recommendation.

Comment: I would never refer to a worm as a bug. That seems to be a pretty significant part of the asker's requirements.

Comment: @talrnu I certainly would, and the definition given by M-W would definitely include them, since they are invertebrates that both creep and crawl.

Comment: That M-W definition sounds like it was inspired by the KJB: _And every creeping thing that creepeth upon the earth shall be an abomination; it shall not be eaten._  ([Leviticus 11:41](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus+11%3A41-43&version=KJV))

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much formal consensus on the meaning of the word - OED makes no mention of "creeping" or "crawling", for example. It boils down to personal preference, which some cursory Googling suggests is more commonly toward the notion that worms are not bugs. Therefore, if you do refer to a worm as a bug, you might not be wrong, but you should certainly be prepared to clarify yourself because the odds are your audience will be confused.

Comment: @talrnu You already said as much, and I already said I disagree. I am not going to change my answer to match your opinion, because I disagree with you. I address the OED's inaccurate statements about how the word is used in North America in my answer. I do not feel that their error deserves more mention than I have already given it. If you wish to do the research to actually back up your statements, and make them more than mere opinion, I suggest you do so and make it an answer, if your research actually does back you up. Either way, continued commenting is inappropriate.

Comment: Again, your answer may or may not be technically correct. I don't intend for you to change it. I'm merely adding to it the observation that it could easily lead to confusion because there is no formal consensus, a fact your answer doesn't make clear. A comment on your answer is the appropriate way to do so - my observation doesn't constitute an entire answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @KRyan: in North American usage, bug is very close and less informal than creepy-crawly (which is even closer).  Since "bugs and worms" is also common, there is somewhat of a distinction between them, but most people would not quibble -- after all, worms "bug" a lot of people as well.

Comment: Seems like part of the conflict between KRyan and tarlnu here could be attributed to regional differences in usage, which can be surprisingly wide in AmE.  I would never call an earthworm a "bug" and I would do a double-take if I heard anyone else do so, but then I have lived in the Pacific Northwest almost all my life.  I'm certainly open to the idea that that usage may be perfectly ordinary elsewhere in the country.  The OED isn't much help validating US dialects and regionalisms, as others have pointed out, since it tends to lump all of AmE together.

Comment: I think we tend to think of invertebrates with external skeletons (arthropods) as being quite distinct from invertebrates with no skeleton or shell at all (worms, slugs). )Then there are snails, which are just slugs traveling in their own RV.)

Comment: I agree with @KRyan. Oxford is fundamentally wrong when it comes to the North American use of the term. All small insects are bugs, but not all bugs are small or insects. I can't imagine someone balking at calling [this](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/12/01/article-2068547-0F02AA4A00000578-492_634x370.jpg) a bug just because it isn't small...

Comment: @talrnu I have pretty much always heard the term bug used for small living thing. As such, I'm siding with KRyan on this. In fact, I'd go so far as to state that bug is even used for microbial things like bacteria and certain protists, informally. Or maybe that last bit is just a bit of slang I picked up because my mother is a nurse.

Comment: @S.Buda There is no side to take. For the last time, I'm not saying *bug* is incorrect. I'm just pointing out the non-negligible probability that someone could be confused if they're expected to know that worms are included in the term. Some people assert that this isn't the case in American English, but I'm American and I know I'd be confused, and other comments from other Americans have suggested the same. There's really nothing left to discuss, unless someone wants to point to some legitimate research on the subject.

Comment: @talrnu There is a side: that just because *you* would be confused, that there is sufficient reason to believe enough people would be confused to warrant inclusion in the answer. So far, as far as I can tell, there is evidence here of at most three people who would even go so far as to be surprised, much less confused. This is literally what the voting mechanism is for, and the votes have shown quite clearly that a substantial number of people, dramatically more than the number of those who have expressed any form of agreement with you, are completely comfortable with this usage.

Comment: @KRyan I stand by my observation: even among Americans, the term *bug* is not unlikely to be misunderstood in a description of worms without clarification. If surplus ELU user upvotes and comments form a sufficient statistical model of your target audience, then you can quibble over the numbers. Otherwise, it's a moot point.

Comment: Just to add a data point: as someone raised in Ohio, "bug" for me includes insects, spiders, and centipedes, but not worms. I have seen books about bugs which included worms, however (which I thought was strange).

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for a negative sense, you might use "vermin" -- small, swarming, repulsive, potentially-disease-bearing creatures.

It's a very unscientific term, including rats, frogs, toads, centipedes, and millipedes, as well as insects and most types of worms (except earthworms and redworms, which are good for the soil). Depending on your sensibilities, it might also include mice, spiders, ants, and termites; it might even encompass scorpions and lizards, and maybe even lobsters.

Comment: @Tushar Raj: Thanks! But you're right, it's a pretty broad term, not something to use when you want precision. I think it dates back to the Middle Ages, which classified animals by habits and habitat much more than by biology. ("Fish" included turtles and whales, for example.)

Comment: This was my first instinct upon reading the question too, though it doesn't fit perfectly. I think for clarity, it would be acceptable to say "worms, bugs and other vermin", for instance, or something similar. On the other hand, simply saying vermin by itself, as in "an abandoned house infested with vermin", would generally imply rats or other vertebrates as well.

Answer (score 12):

> preferably not too informal

This is the most formal one: they are all [invertebrates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertebrate).

> Invertebrates are animals that neither possess nor develop a vertebral column, derived from the notochord. This includes all animals apart from the subphylum Vertebrata. Familiar examples of invertebrates include **insects**, crabs, lobsters and their kin, snails, clams, octopuses and their kin, starfish, sea-urchins and their kin, and **worms**.

But the usage depends on the context.

If your text is somehow related to science, don't call spider an "insect". Spiders & insects are ["arthropods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) (not "arthropod**e**s"), together with worms they are "invertebrates".

Comment: I believe, in English, it is "arthropod" and "arthropods" (no e after the d). From *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*: *arthropod* -- an individual of the phylum Arthropoda.

Comment: @JLG yes, you are right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The problem with "invertebrate" is that it's far too broad, as your passage makes clear.

Comment: @JasonMelançon it could be specified with adjectives, like "small invertebrates", "land invertebrates". But I avoided offering variants, as I do not have the proper feeling of language and cannot say if one is good or bad. Not a native speaker, alas.

Comment: @JasonMelançon also, there's little information on the context. The accepted answer is "minibeasts". As I feel, it is only appropriate for a fairy-tale or some cartoon. But the OP found it acceptable for their context.

Comment: I'm not sure that a word that includes things like clams and jellyfish really fits the OP's intent.

Answer (score 5):

"Vermin" or "pests" can be any small creature, usually with a negative connotation, but including things as large as rats or even opossums. "Creepy-crawlies" is good but very informal. But as for "bug" -- scientifically, only a small subset of insects are bugs. But the word has expanded, and can now also mean an infection, or a computer glitch.  I would argue that as long as the context doesn't imply you mean only insects, "bug" isn't actually wrong in informal English.

(Scientifically, both worms and insects are invertebrates -- creatures without an internal spine -- which then includes spiders and even coral.)

Comment: "scientifically, only a small subset of insects are bugs. But the word has expanded" -- well, the scientists contracted the meaning for scientific purposes by using an existing English word with a new jargon meaning. Civilians ignored this contraction, and also expanded it further with new meanings.

Comment: c.f: "mathematically, a group is a monoid with inverses. But the word has expanded. I would argue that calling the Beatles a group, or a "pop group", isn't actually wrong in informal English" ;-)

Comment: Steve: perhaps.  My biology friends insist that it originally meant a subset of insects and has diverged; http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bug seems to disagree. The argument still stands, though.

Answer (score 4):

**[Minibeast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minibeast)** - this term is commonly used (at least in the UK) by charities and other groups which involve children in outdoor activities learning about nature. See also Cbeebies [*Minibeasts with Jess*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/cbeebies/shows/mini-beast-adventure-with-jess)

The UK organisation [Buglife](https://www.buglife.org.uk/bugs-and-habitats/all-about-bugs) works to protect ALL invertebrates regardless of size or number of legs, and uses the term *bug* to encompass all of these.

> Invertebrates are animals without backbones and make up the great
>   majority of animal life, with 40,000 species in Britain alone and many
>   millions on Earth.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in the Swedish language the word "kryp" have this meaning. Small creatures that is not built like us mammals, birds and fish. Non vegetable things that move around, but do not have a skeleton. (Or we just can't tell.)

A direct translation to English would be "crawl". But "crawlers" would perhaps correspond more closely to how it is perceived. Yes, it comes from the verb crawl, even if many of them can jump, fly and swim. But it is usually when they crawl on our bodies we notice them.

The word often have a negative association to it, but not necessary.

Comment: _But it is usually when they crawl on our bodies we notice them_ You sold me. +1 for the information, even though the term is probably unusable in English.

Answer (score 0):

In french, it is common to see products to kill calling them *"**indésirables**"* or *"**nuisibles**"*.

You can translate to get :

> **undesirable**, unwanted, unwelcome, **pest**

Comment: "Undesirable" could be interpreted as referring to people.

Comment: @Kevin You are totally right, but since I don't know where this word will be used, *context* can be leading to insect like reference... or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Wug** is a portmanteau of *worm* and *bug*. It's not very common though, and might need to be explained.

A Google search for [`wug worm bug`](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=wug%20worm%20bug) reveals hundreds of results, many from books on taxonomy. I couldn't just search for `wug` because it has other meanings as well.

This is either very informal or very formal -- i can't quite tell. :P