# What do you call a bug collection?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

[Entomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomology) is the study of insects, which can informally include [minibeasts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250245) that aren't scientifically classified as insects. Professional and amateur entomologists sometimes maintain [bug collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_collecting).

Is there a single word for such a collection - a curated assortment of various species of bugs? Kind of how:

- a beekeeper keeps bees in an *apiary*
- animals of various sorts are kept in a *menagerie* or *zoo*
- taxidermalogical mounts might be presented in a *diorama*
- a philatelist collects stamps in an *album*

So, an entomologist keeps bugs in a(n) __________ .

Notes:

- Implying that the insects are living or dead isn't required. (Either implication is fine.)
- Implying professional or amateur interest isn't required. (Either implication is fine.)
- A phrase is fine, as long as it doesn't include the synonyms of "insect/bug/minibeast" or "collection". Because then "bug collection" would do :)

Comment: hmmm, _minibestiary_? :)

Comment: insectisite? insectorium?

Comment: ... . glass-jar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ***[insectarium](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/insectarium)*** or *insectary* is, per Oxford Living Dictionaries,

> A place where insects are kept, exhibited, and studied.

In practice, web searches suggest that *insectarium* is preferred for institutions which function as zoos for live insects, whereas *insectary* refers to the raising of insects, whether for institutional research or to attract beneficial insects to one's garden.

For example, some institutions for public education include The Insectarium, a component of the [Space for Life](http://espacepourlavie.ca/en/insectarium) (Espace pour la vie) in Montreal; the [Philadelphia Insectarium and Butterfly Pavilion](https://www.phillybutterflypavilion.com/); the [Audubon Butterfly Garden and Insectarium](https://audubonnatureinstitute.org/insectarium) in New Orleans; and the forthcoming [Insectarium of Victoria](http://www.insectarium.org/), about an hour outside Melbourne. *Insect zoo* is another term for these public-facing collections, like the Smithsonian Institution's [O. Orkin Insect Zoo](https://www.si.edu/Exhibitions/Insect-Zoo-O-Orkin-132) or the [Insect Zoo at the Portland Zoo](https://www.oregonzoo.org/discover/exhibits/insect-zoo).

On the other hand, facilities where insects are raised primarily for research seem to favor *insectary*, from the [U.S. Department of Agriculture](https://www.ars.usda.gov/plains-area/mhk/cgahr/docs/insectary/) to the [Colorado Department of Agriculture](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/InsectaryBrochure.pdf), to the entomology or agriculture programs of many U.S. research universities.

Collections primarily of dead insects kept for research or display may simply be referred to as *insect collections*, like the [Iowa State Insect Collection](https://www.ent.iastate.edu/insectcollection/) or the [Cornell University Insect Collection](http://cuic.entomology.cornell.edu/).

---

The *-arium* or *-orium* suffix, borrowed from Latin, is often used to produce words about a place associated with something, like *aquarium* or *auditorium* which may be familiar to you. A *[xylarium](http://herbarium.desu.edu/collections/Xylarium/xylarium.html)* is a wood collection, a *[formicarium](https://www.antkeepers.com/keeping-ants/formicariums/)* is a pretentious ant farm.

Answer (score 3):

An earlier answer, *insectarium* for living insects, satisfies your parallels with living bees (an *apiary*) and animals (a *zoo* or *menagerie*). That is,

> **insectarium**, *n.*
>   A place for keeping and breeding insects; an entomological vivarium.
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

The insectarium, however, is a curated collection of *living* bugs.

For displays of collections of dead bugs (*entomotaxy*), two terms satisfy your parallels with taxidermy (*diorama*) and philately (*album*). Those terms are combinative (just as are *taxidermological diorama* and *stamp album*), but in the appropriate context the terms may be used to good purpose without prepending the combining term *insect*:

> **insect-box**, *n.*
>   ....
>   **insect-cabinet**, *n.*
>
> [*OED*](http://oed.com/)

As suggested by the usual meanings of *box* and *cabinet*, the former is usually associated with a smaller scale, more temporary display and arrangement of bugs (or a subdivision of a *cabinet*), and the latter with a larger and more permanent display.

Here is a general description of an insect-cabinet, from [*Directions for collecting and preserving insects* (A.S. Packard, 1873)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044107286676;view=1up;seq=19):

> *Insect-cabinet.* For permanent exhibition, a cabinet of shallow drawers, protected by doors, is most useful. A drawer may be eighteen by twenty inches square, and two inches deep in the the clear, and provided with a tight glass cover. For constant use, baxes made of thin, well-seasoned wood, with tight fitting covers, are indispensable. For Coleoptera, Dr. Leconte recommends that they be twelve by nine inches (inside measurement). For the larger Lepidoptera a little larger box is preferable. Others prefer boxes made in the form of books, which may be put away like books on the shelves of the cabinet, though the cover of the box is apt to be in the way.

The style and details of *insect-box* and *insect-cabinet* construction and appointment vary widely.

Answer (score 1):

Museums call them collections. When referring to a specific collection it is prefixed with the type, for example plant collection, herbaceous plant collection, insect collection. Here are [some examples](https://www.fieldmuseum.org/science/research) of actual use at the the Field Museum.

Bug collection is informal and sounds to me like something a child would keep. Insect collection is more formal.

Answer (score 1):

I have only ever seen them referred to as collections. To add a more professional third-party credential, the Audubon Butterfly Garden and Insectarium in New Orleans refers to various assortments as such.

It's also important to point out that *diorama* and *album* are non-exclusive, and can refer to multiple types of collections. A particular bug collection could (depending on whether the collection is of living or dead insects) also be referred to as a diorama, album, gallery, and so on, depending on how it's presented.